# Remove duplicate with Merge in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle19c

I have a table without a primary key where more than 13,000 records are duplicates on the OBJID column, but the values in the other columns are different. I want to merge both duplicate records into a single one. Is it possible to do this with a merge statement or do I need to update the table with a loop and fix it manually?

Here is how the table looks:
[image]

> OBJID,INVKLASSE,NETTTYPE,NAVN,ALT_NAVN,ON_ID,ON_TYPE,ON_STED_NR,ON_OVER_ID
> -219468,NYINVESTERING,,,,,,,
> -219468,,,,,277615,50,277614,-99
> -218981,NYINVESTERING,,,,,,,
> -218981,,,,,277335,50,277334,-99
> -218761,NYINVESTERING,,,,,,,
> -218761,,,,,277909,50,277908,-99
> -218709,NYINVESTERING,,,,,,,
> -218709,,,,,284646,50,284645,-99

I have created a temporary table and I am trying to insert all duplicate records where OBJID is the primary key.

```
select * from (
select
   objid,INVKLASSE,NETTTYPE,NAVN,ALT_NAVN,ON_ID,ON_TYPE,ON_STED_NR,ON_OVER_ID,
   row_number() over(partition by objid order by objid) as DUP
from USEROPENNIS
)
where dup=2;
```

I have created some SQL like this to separate all duplicate records where DUP=1 or 2. All DUP=1 can be inserted as unique records, but DUP=2 is 13,000 records where I need to update the table where all columns are null or something similar.

I'm looking for suggestions on anything that can quickly fix it.

Expected output.
[image]

Comment: Please restructure the question and separate this parts: 1. Your current data (as some representative sample dataset in text format). 2. Your desired output (again as a text in tabular format). 3. The rules to transfrom source to the target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To collapse duplicate records into one while picking column values from each, you will need to use a `GROUP BY` on your primary key combined with aggregate functions  (like `MAX`) around all your non-key columns, with possible `DECODE`/`CASE` inside each aggregate that try to decide which values to prioritize.

If your only issue is some rows have `NULL` for all the columns and other rows have data, then delete the rows with `NULL` values. Or if it's mixed but still only a `NULL` vs. non-`NULL` issue, `MAX` by itself will pick out the non-`NULL` value. If it's more complicated than this and you have multiple non-`NULL` values to choose from, you have to write the logic to pick the one you want.

At its simplest:

```
SELECT objid,
       MAX(invklasse),MAX(nettype),MAX(navn), etc...
  FROM USEROPENNIS
GROUP BY objid
```

More complex (this can look like anything, this just gives the general idea):

```
SELECT objid,
       MAX(NULLIF(invklasse,'BADVALUE')),
       SUBSTR(MIN(DECODE(nettype,'nicevalue','1','lessnicevalue','2','3')||nettype),2) nettype, etc..
  FROM USEROPENNIS
GROUP BY objid
```

Once you get the data the way you want it in your `SELECT` query, you place the query you come up with in a CTAS to create a temp table:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp$1 AS SELECT ...
```

Now truncate the original table and insert into it the contents of your temporary table:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE useropennis;
INSERT /*+ append */ INTO useropennis SELECT * FROM tmp$1;
COMMIT;
```

Now create a PK on it so you don't get into this situation again:

```
ALTER TABLE useropennis ADD CONSTRAINT pk_useropennis PRIMARY KEY (objid);
```

Comment: wow, this is actually works. it save my times to get it done manually. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE A new Table like this

```
CREATE TABLE USEROPENNIS (objid int, INVKLASSE varchar2(10))
```

```
INSERT INTO USEROPENNIS VALUES (12,NULL)
```

```
INSERT INTO USEROPENNIS VALUES (12,'A')
```

```
INSERT INTO USEROPENNIS VALUES (14,'B')
```

```
INSERT INTO USEROPENNIS VALUES (14,NULL)
```

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS SELECT objid , MAX(INVKLASSE) as INVKLASSE FROM USEROPENNIS GROUP BY  objid
```

```
2 rows affected
```

```
SELECT * FROM new_table
```

| OBJID | INVKLASSE |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | A |
| 14 | B |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/djrvesOT)

Then DROP the old table

And then

```
RENAME new_table TO USEROPENNIS ;
```